# Django Foreign key queries

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

In the following model:

```
class header(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id()

class criteria(models.Model):
    details =   models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    headerid = models.ForeignKey(header)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id()

class options(models.Model):
    opt_details =   models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    headerid = models.ForeignKey(header)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id()
```

If there is a row in the database for table header as
        `Id=1,    title=value-mart  ,      createdby=CEO`

How do I query criteria and options tables to get all the values related to header table
 id=1

Also can some one please suggest a good link for queries examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, don't use `id` in the names, because it is confusing. That field isn't the ID, it is the object itself. (If you have a field `ref` it automatically creates a field `ref_id`)

```
options.objects.filter(header=a_header)
```

You query it like any value, where some header instance is the value you are filtering on.

Answer (score 22):

Ironfroggy is right, but there is another more obvious way to get the relevant `options` and `criteria` objects. Django automatically creates a 'reverse relation' for every foreign key pointing at a model, and that is usually the name of the related model plus `_set`. So:

```
mycriteria.options_set.all()
mycriteria.header_set.all()
```

will give you all the `options` and `header` objects related to a `criteria` object `mycriteria`.

Also, a note on style: as ironfroggy pointed out, you shouldn't use `id` in the foreign key fields, but also you should use Capitalised style for your model classes, so you can see a difference between the class `Criteria` and a particular instance `criteria`.

In terms of links, the [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/) is excellent and explains all of this.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest trying to us a [coding style](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/#model-style) and naming convention that is more like you see in the Django documentation for [Models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#topics-db-models).  Something more like this:

```
class Header(models.Model):
    ...

class Criteria(models.Model):
    details = model.CharField(max_length=255)
    header = models.ForeignKey(Header)
```

And then query them as needed:

```
# find Criteria for a given header
value_mart = Header.objects.get(id=1)

# ... via an instance of Header.
value_mart.criteria_set.all()

# ... or with a filter().
Criteria.objects.filter(header=value_mart)
Criteria.objects.filter(header_id=1)
```

The documentation for [many-to-one relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships) also references a [usage example](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_one/).

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are looking for [Following relationships "backward"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

You can get the header object you want to filter by, and use something like

```
obj = Header.objects.get(title="value-mart", "createdby=CEO")
obj.criteria_set.all()
```

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for more detailed info